# "Could not find a part of the path," on path that does exist

Tags: c#

I am attempting to update the lock screen background like this:

```
 string filename = @"C:\app\screenshot.temp.jpg";
 string finalLocation = @"C:\Windows\System32\oobe\info\backgrounds\backgroundDefault.jpg";
 File.Move(filename, finalLocation);
```

Unfortunately this throws a System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException exception:

```
 An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
 Additional information: Could not find a part of the path.
```

However when i browse to C:\Windows\System32\oobe\info\backgrounds in Windows Explorer, CMD, or Powershell it does exist. I also have the security to write, rename, and delete files in that location (and the C# process is running in my context). What is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've encountered this, I am guessing you're executing the process on a 64 bit version of Windows.

**Background**:

On Windows 32 bit, there is a single System32 folder called "System32" that stores all 32 bit DLLs. On Windows 64 bit, there are two "System32" folders one still called System32 and another called SysWOW64.

These two folders store the opposite of what their names imply:

- System32 stores 64 bit DLLs.
- SysWOW64 stores 32 bit DLLs.

SysWOW64 stands for "Windows 32-bit on Windows 64-bit." So it is a folder that exists for backwards compatibility with 32 bit for 32 bit processes.

**Why this breaks things?**

Microsoft are obsessed with backwards compatibility, so when they added 32 bit emulation on 64 bit Windows, they wanted to make the bitness of the system invisible to the 32 bit processes running, and they introduced a bunch of compatibility shims (fixes).

One of these shims redirects IO requests for %WINDIR%\System32 to %WINDIR%\SysWOW64 for processes running in 32 bit mode only.

So when you request a move from:

```
 C:\Windows\System32\oobe\info\backgrounds\backgroundDefault.jpg
```

Windows may actually instead request the move from:

```
 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oobe\info\backgrounds\backgroundDefault.jpg
```

Which does not exist. Thus explaining the error you're seeing.

**The Fix**

The easiest fix is to change your program to build as a 64 bit process. You can do this by:

Right Click on the Project -> Properties -> Build [Tab] -> Platform target -> x64

Now when you run, requests against %WINDIR%\System32 should actually hit %WINDIR%\System32 for real.

Alternatively if you *need* to run your process in 32 bit mode (e.g. due to library compatibility) you can ask Windows to disable the shim like this:

```
 [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
 public static extern bool Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(ref IntPtr ptr);

 private static void Main(string[] args)
 { 
   IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr();
   bool isWow64FsRedirectionDisabled = Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(ref ptr); 
  }
```

In either case requests should be handled more literally by the operating system, and you can update the lock screen background (or any other operation in System32).